# I cant seem to remove the # symbol from website

Tags: vue.js

my website is https://jaylanthedev.com/#/ but for some reason it needs to # sign to get to any other page that is not the homepage. I am very confused as to why this is. It is a vue app hosted on azure and after googling I am not able to get very far with this. Also not sure if this is a vue problem or a azure problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Ex:
Works: https://jaylanthedev.com/#/about
Does not work: https://jaylanthedev.com/about

Comment: Where's the code that setup the endpoint for ```/about```?

Comment: @Inogueir I have this on github here https://github.com/jaysnel/portfolio-site/blob/master/src/router/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read here:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to
> simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL
> changes.

So Vue has a default hash to load its routes.
To switch to history mode:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: routes
})
```

But - this means that you need a server to render your pages. You need to have your client be running on a node server like express or anything similar so it can route the pages without re-rendering.